# How to generate a secured query string link using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, query-string

The html code is:

```
<a href="room/info/{{$value->id}}">Click to show details</a>
```

And this code is generating this type of link:

```
localhost:8000/room/info/2
```

The router is:

```
Router::get('room/info/{id}', 'roomcontroller@details');
```

Where numeric '2' is the id of a room.

But I think it's unsecured. Because an user can change the id from a browser address bar. Now I want to know is there any secured way in Laravel framework to use a query string? Or is there any other way to do the operation securely using Laravel?

Comment: You can't prevent someone from changing the `2` to anything else in the url. Your best bet would be some sort of access control that says what room the user can access, something like a password for entering some rooms or don't use a number, use a string like URL shorteners use. The last option will also really only make it harder to guess a room name, not impossible.

Comment: You can use a `hashed key` instead of a simple `id`. It would require a bit of effort from the user to "guess" the hash than guessing a simple increasing id number.

Comment: I was also thinking about this solution, I know it will be better, but I'm curious about anything better is existing or not? by the way, thanks for your suggestion. @OfirBaruch

Comment: And also thanks to Jonathan @JonathanKuhn

Comment: If it's a user based system, you can always compare the user's id to the room's id. If not, using an hashed key is a good idea. You can consider adding a "password request" in the page itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent users entering rooms that they are not allowed to by using a [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware). Each request is passed to all registered middlewares for this route, before the controller is reached. So you can easily check if user is authorized to view this room.

In Laravel 5 you can create middleware very easy:

```
php artisan make:middleware RoomMiddleware
```

A new file will be generated in `app/Http/Middleware`. You can write your logic there:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoomMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // You can make your checks here, like if
        // the user is logged in and he can view
        // this room
        $roomId = $request->input('id');
        if (\Auth::guest() || !\Auth::user()->isAuthorized($roomId)) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Note that this is just an example. The function `isAuthorized` does not exists, you have to implement your logic there.

You then need to set alias for your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'room' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RoomMiddleware',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
];
```

You can then set this middleware to your route, like this:

```
Route::get('room/info/{id}', ['middleware' => 'room', 'uses' => 'roomcontroller@details']);
```

In Laravel 4.2 you have similar thing, but it is called [Route Filters](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters).